# Infinite loop Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
import React from 'react';
// import { getAllData } from '../../data/data-source';

function ArtikelPage() {
  const [artikel, setArtikel] = React.useState([]);
  setArtikel(['ari', 'ahmad', 'putra']);

  // getAllData('artikel')
  //   .then((result) => {
  //     setArtikel(result);
  //   });

  return (
    <div>
      <p className="artikel">Artikel</p>
      {artikel.map((artikel2) => (
        <div className="card">
          <img src={artikel2} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{artikel2}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">{artikel2}</p>
            <a href="ww" className="btn btn-primary">Lihat</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ArtikelPage;
```

I try to make a looping for some card element,but console.log Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: You're setting the state right after rendering the component.

Comment: If you want to initialize the `artikel` state variable, you can remove the statement `setArtikel(['ari', 'ahmad', 'putra']);` and replace the `const [artikel, setArtikel] = React.useState([]);` with `const [artikel, setArtikel] = React.useState(['ari', 'ahmad', 'putra']);`

Answer (score 2):

You've got the wrong way to init the `artikel` state, here are two ways to fix it:
1:

```
const [artikel, setArtikel] = React.useState(['ari', 'ahmad', 'putra']);
```

2:

```
const [artikel, setArtikel] = React.useState([]);
React.useEffect(() => {
    setArtikel(['ari', 'ahmad', 'putra']);
}, [])
```

Hope it can help you